# What is the site self-evaluation?

Tags: support, review

Today I encountered the site self-evaluation evenmt. When I clicked on it the review site opened and I had to evaluate several questions. However this thing lacked some explanation. So what is the reason for this evaluation? Where can I see the result and what happens with the result?

Comment: Helpful: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165994/203389

Comment: @Seth Looks like another "announcement" by SE *after* it has been deployed. Saw this on UL earlier on as well. Can't believe this.

Comment: We do these regularly, what's the problem?

Comment: @JorgeCastro To me, the current one-line explanation is very confusing and makes me think this is a bug of some sort. The only thing I come up with were in-beta phase SE sites to do this. Any additional explanation why *we* need this...?

Comment: It's a good indicator to find out how users of the site consider the overall quality of the answers.

Comment: @gertvdijk: No, this was already in place. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues/161391#161391 . And mods can see when the next eval is in their dash (though I agree that we should have gotten a warning first, since this was happening for the first time on graduated sites). However, I don't see the harm of starting this on graduated sites before announcing it (AFAICT it was automatic).